# No data scraping a table using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the first table (FINRA TRACE Bond Market Activity) of this website using Google Apps Script and I'm getting no data.
https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/TRACEMarketAggregateStats.jsp
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojWzy.png)

```js
function myFunction() {

  const url = 'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/TRACEMarketAggregateStats.jsp';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);

  var data = $('table').first().text();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

I have also tried from this page and I do not get any result.
[https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/transferPage.jsp?path=http%3A%2F%2Fmuni-internal.morningstar.com%2Fpublic%2FMarketBreadth%2FC&_=1655503161665](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ORL.png)

I can't find a solution on the web and I ask you for help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page does a lot of things in the background. First, there is a POST request to `https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/finralogin.jsp` that initiates the session. Then, XHR requests are made to load the data tables. If you grab the cookie by POST'ing to that login page, you can pass it on the desired XHR call. That will return the table. The date you want to fetch the data for can be set with the `date` URL paramter. Here is an example:

```
function fetchFinra() {
  const LOGIN_URL = "https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/finralogin.jsp";
  const DATE = "06/24/2022" //the desired date

  let opts = {
    method: "POST",
    payload: JSON.stringify({redirectPage: "/BondCenter/TRACEMarketAggregateStats.jsp"})
  };
  
  let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(LOGIN_URL, opts);
  let cookies = res.getAllHeaders()["Set-Cookie"];
  
  const XHR_URL = `https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/transferPage.jsp?path=http%3A%2F%2Fmuni-internal.morningstar.com%2Fpublic%2FMarketBreadth%2FC&_=${new Date().getTime()}&date=${DATE}`;

  res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(XHR_URL, { headers: {'Cookie': cookies.join(";")}} );
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res.getContentText());

  var data = $('table td').text();
  
  Logger.log(data);
}
```